# What is a milder example for "fascinated" or "amazed"?

Tags: word-request

I'm writting an email for a professor <strike>which</strike> who I'm interested in making a collaboration with and I want to say that I really liked the results of one of his work. However I don't want to sound fake as the results are not special nor extremely stellar, they are simply good.

How can I say it?
The phrase I'm working on is this one:
"While searching for possible contacts, I came across your personal page and was able to read some of your works regarding the implementation of computational tools in undergraduate curriculum and was **XXXXXX** by the results."

Answer (score 1):

"*I was very interested in the results*" sounds natural. Keen, but not over the top.

Please consider making it **two** sentences:

*While searching for possible contacts I came across your personal page and read some of your work/writing on the implementation of computational tools in the undergraduate curriculum. I was very interested in the results.*

**works** is fine if you read several essays or treatises. Otherwise use **work** if it was e.g. a research paper, or **writing** if not.

If it is only one curriculum say "*in **the** undergraduate curriculum*," otherwise say "*in undergraduate **curricula***."

Comment: **you should never use “works” to describe the work you do when you’re sitting at a desk**.  https://blog.harwardcommunications.com/2011/02/21/don’t-confuse-“work”-and-“works”/

Comment: @Brad: [Lexico: definition 3](https://www.lexico.com/definition/work)